# Autokey NTP client?

Tags: macos, certificate, clock, ntp

What's a reasonably short path to getting OS X to be an NTP client of an NTP server, using **autokey**?

I tried adding the server's public keyfile (iffpar) and the appropriate commands in ntp.conf in the same way that works on a Linux client, but I'm not getting an authenticated connection from the OS X (10.8.5) client.

Contents of **/private/etc/ntp.conf**:

```
crypto pw «clientpassword»
keysdir /private/etc/ntp
server «my_ntp_server» autokey
```

Files in **/private/etc/ntp/** directory:

```
ntpkey_iffpar_«my_ntp_server».3600540412
ntpkey_iffpar_«my_ntp_server»@ -> ntpkey_iffpar_«my_ntp_server».3600540412
```

Comment: I am assuming you mean autokey and not autopath? The last time I checked you need to rebuild OSX's ntp in order to get autokey working.

Comment: Yes, **autokey**, thank you. Fixed. By "rebuild", do you mean replacing the OS X NTP with one built from some source repo? Is there an OS X-compatible source, somewhere?

Comment: Yes rebuild means recompile the sources. http://www.ntp.org